# Why are my aloe's leaves bent and drying up, and what can I do to help it grow?

Tags: diagnosis, leaves, aloe

My aloe plant is not growing right. I've had it for about a year and the leaves are bending and drying up. Please help me because I don't want it to die, they are very beautiful plants. Can I transplant it in the winter? I just don't know what to do, it’s dying from the tip to the base of the plaint. I can’t give you a picture because this is my first time posting on this site.

Comment: Which variety of Aloe is it? Are you keeping it as a houseplant, or is it growing outside? If outside, what part of the world are you in?

Comment: a picture is worth several hundred words.

Comment: Overwatering is a frequent cause of aloe demise: http://www.ehow.com/info_8544310_signs-over-watering-aloe-vera.html

Answer (score 3):

I will suggest that you  check on the following:

1. Is it getting proper sunlight and moderate amount of water to keeps its soil moist.
2. Has your plant has overgrown that pot, i.e. if the plant has grown more as compared to the size of the pot, then you need to transfer it into a bigger container.
3. Otherwise I suggest to replant it so that soil gets loosened up. Also, add some organic fertilizer while replanting, and check the growth after 15-20 days. Also if you find any insects near the roots, then re-pot it with the fresh soil and wash the roots with clean water before potting it.